# ASP.NET Core MVC web app, updating my database from partial view

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to update a record in a database on user command and I'm wondering best approach to do it. I'm guessing I lack the correct terminology to research the appropriate tools and patterns I should be using.

**First**

I started trying to write a Javascript function that could call the c# serverside function, but I'm under the suspicion that I'm leaving out a lot of the power and functionality that would come with making a ASP.NET Core application.

**Second**

Razor pages are supposed to be a replacement to ASP.NET Core MVC so it seems like it should be redundant to add in the MVC system along side dependency injection setup to return the view components. So I think there must be a way to do this through razor pages rather than muddying up the project with model, view, controller folders.

The project is setup the same as ASP.NET Core template in VS, except rebuilt without bootstrap.

So it has a `_layout.cshtml`, which uses a partial view to render the user menu.

If it helps, the website is studiobreifcase.com, and public in my git repo.

https://github.com/TAReber/StudioBriefcase-Web-App

You could clone it and run it, but I'm not sure what will work and what won't without access to azure.

The current goal is to just log the output in the console.

`_menuPartial.cshtml`, included in `_layout.cshtml`:

```
@{
}

    // ... irrelevant code

    @if (Context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        // ...
        <select id="Menu_RoleDropdown" onchange="updateUserRole()">
            <option value="Default">Anonymous</option>
            <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
            // ...
        </select>
    }
    else 
    { 
        // OAuth Login stuff
        // irrelevant code
        ...
    }

    <script>
            async function updateUserRole() {
                var selectedRole = document.getElementById("Menu_RoleDropdown").value;
                console.log(selectedRole);

                // Attempted to access a function in UserService.cs but failed.            
            }
   </script>
```

`UserService.cs`:

```
namespace StudioBriefcase.Services
{
    public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        // ... Members, Constructor and other methods.

        // Function  I failed to call
        public Task SetUserRole(string role)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Setting user Role to {role}");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just looking at generating log outputs in this attempt. I didn't succeed. Its probably good I didn't succeed because I don't know what I'm doing and its bound to be bad my first time.

I guess the question is a bit broad, but Any help with what patterns and practices I should/could use to get connect to the API would be helpful.

Comment: Just a quick update.

I studied a bunch of stuff, watched some videos, and eventually ended up reading a bunch of stuff on razor pages.

I think a big issue I'm dealing with is that my partial view isn't a razor page. I think @RenderBody() can only render one model at a time.

The conclusion is that because I was trying to work in side a partial view instead of an actual razor page, I'm making this more complicated than it needs.

My new solution is to splash the user settings on this screen in a new window. Hope this can be a razor page separate from the browser url.

Comment: in general, partials are only used to break up larger .cshtml files.  They're not needed at all, and they would work with the same models/controllers as the parent razor page.  Razor pages are built with MVC... they're just a sort of pre-packaged version... mainly by extending a "PageModel" object.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: To update a database record in ASP.NET Core with Razor Pages, add a Controller with an API endpoint. Your JavaScript function, triggered by user action, should call this API using AJAX (e.g., `fetch`). The API method will invoke `SetUserRole` in `UserService` to update the user role in the database. Partial views can be used for UI elements but manage AJAX calls as in full Razor Pages.

Comment: I got the role to update through a new razor page I created. The OP seems completely unnecessary now.

Tim Corey's video helped.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68towqYcQlY&t=2973s)

The current solution is little more than a prototype and I still feel insecure about how sloppy it is. I'll be looking changing it into something nicer.

I'll post an answer when I have a nicer answer.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few week doing another project. But it cleared my head a little bit when I went back to this. I attempted to follow Jalpa's response.

It's not quite like he has it, I created a `UserController` that Ajax would connect to, the `UserController` calls the function in `UserService`.

I don't know if this is better, but I thought it would keep the entire `UserService` from being part of the API.

I mapped the controller route in the `Program.cs`, minimal API.

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "api",
pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

I am paranoid about my application being secure. I don't know what it should look like. I thought I could at least add a check that might help me detect suspicious behavior.

```cs
namespace StudioBriefcase.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
  [Route("api/user")]
  public class UserController : Controller
  {
    private readonly UserService _userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService)
    {
      _userService = userService;
    }

    //TODO:: Learn how to use ILogger and come up with some standardized system to log errors
    [HttpPost("UpdateUserClass")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserClass([FromBody] UserRoleUpdateModel model)
    {

      if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        if (model.Id == User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value)
        {
          if (uint.TryParse(model.Id, out uint id))
          {
            //Console.WriteLine(id);
            await _userService.SetUserClass(id, model.userclass);
            return Ok(new { Message = "Successfully Updated role to ", model.userclass });
          }
          else
          {
            return Ok(new { Message = "Failed to Change Role" });
          }
        }
        else
        {
          return Ok(new { Message = "Wrong User ID Submitted, Is this a Hack Attempt?" });
        }
      }
      return Ok(new { Message = "User Identity was Null, UserController.UpdateUserClass Method" });
    }

  }
}
```

I forgot, but my first time using the fetch operation was some test code I wrote to scrap public data from youtube through the google api. That helped me understand what I was doing. I can call this javascript with a button or something.

```html
<script>
    function updateUserRole(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        var selectedRole = document.getElementById('Menu_RoleDropdown').value;
        var userId = '@User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value';

        fetch('/api/user/UpdateUserClass', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                Id: userId,
                userClass: selectedRole
            })
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Fetch Operation failed in _menuPartial.cshtml:", error);
            });
    }
</script>
```